# Restore desktop unsaved files after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, windows-update

I'm kind of desperate, yesterday I had a bunch of tabs opened in private mode that I need for my research (my Firefox profile is set to start by default in private mode) and many opened and unsaved Notepad files with data I've been collecting for almost a month.

Today, Windows 10 updated while I left the computer sleeping and now everything is gone!

I know it's very irresponsible to leave these things unsaved, on the other hand I wasn't expecting to have a sudden reboot by Windows. Is there any way to recover these files? Does Windows save the machine state before updating? I can't go over everything again, some information would be lost that I don't even know how to retrieve it, I can't remember what annotations I did. Everything was closed and lost, only Word files were recovered.

Thank you so much

Comment: Firefox session is obviously gone since it was a private session.  Unsaved notepad files also would be gone.  Windows continuous creates notifications when a pending update has been installed and a reboot is scheduled

Comment: Reminds me of 20 years ago when I used to manually save everything I was working on every 10 minutes in case something crashed, which it did frequently. I can sympathise, but not saving your work on a platform that itself will not autosave is just an accident waiting to happen. It's like not keeping your backup up to date - all it needs is one small accident...

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, not this time, I had no notification at all when I went to sleep and left my computer sleeping. Now that I woke up everything is gone. And I agree with you Tetsujin, but I wasn't expecting this. I've also blocked with firewall Windows update servers, I guess Windows found a workaround the firewall and updated itself

Comment: I'd look into buying a Mac next time ;) That's obviously a joke, but it's really only *half* a joke, Macs will return to where they left off through restarts, even for unsaved documents. You can also switch off automatic updates with reasonable granularity & will never be forced into an update in the middle of work. Nothing can get your incognito pages back though… that's a side effect of being incognito; that data isn't stored.